# How do I get the "custimize the activity" menu back in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, menu

It seems that in older versions of android studio when starting a new project after selecting the activity type there used to be a menu titled "Customize the activity" and I wanted to know if there was a way to get it back.[image: Customize the activity menu]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ctrl + F6, it's called refactor. just select and hit and you be able to customize what you want

Comment: Yeah that's what i get for following an outdated tutorial.  I see what you mean about refactoring my code now though, thanks